# How do I auto trigger a build from pushing into the repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How do I auto trigger a build from pushing into the repo?

I tried the Branch policy but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in the **Triggers** of the build pipeline. 
Checking **Enable continuous integration** option and setting the branch filters.
After this setup, when there is a new commit push to the branch included in the branch filters, the build will be triggered.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work. I'll try again. Thanks

Comment: 'It didn't seem to work' specifically refer to what ?What difficulties have you encountered?